# Waitting Time ( TTFB ) is above 4 seconds result from `get_headers()`

Tags: php

I am using Apache version ( httpd-2.4.10-win64-VC11 ) on windows 2012. I am trying to do that when click on image item it would open dialog with inforamation about this item. I do this with :

```
var self = $(this),
  vaid = "1",
  btnhref = self.attr('href'),
  itemID = getVar("item",btnhref);

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/action.php',
  data: {"itemID" : itemID},
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {                     
    xhr.setRequestHeader('va', vaid);                                  
  },
  statusCode: {
    401:function() { Validation('401 Unauthorized</br>Error: Invalid Action'); }
  },
  complete: function()
  {       
    var state = {
      "dialog": true
    };
    history.pushState(state, document.title, btnhref);                              
  },
  success: function(response){},
  cache: true,
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  processData: true
});
```

The problem is that the response is very slow and I am unable to find the reason for it. Below I add the data I received from chrome speed tracer.

P.S : I am using cloudfront for images , CSS & Javascripts files .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEh2Q.png

**EDIT :** This details from fiddler web debugger: ( with GET or POST the same results )

== TIMING INFO ============

ClientConnected:    13:53:10.037

ClientBeginRequest: 13:53:10.064

GotRequestHeaders:  13:53:10.064

ClientDoneRequest:  13:53:10.064

Determine Gateway:  0ms

DNS Lookup:         1ms

TCP/IP Connect: 16ms

HTTPS Handshake:    0ms

ServerConnected:    13:53:10.080

FiddlerBeginRequest:    13:53:10.080

ServerGotRequest:   13:53:10.080

ServerBeginResponse:    13:53:10.593

GotResponseHeaders: 13:53:10.593

**ServerDoneResponse:   13:53:15.366**

ClientBeginResponse:    13:53:15.366

ClientDoneResponse: 13:53:15.366

**Apache Log : LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined**

```
37.8.80.203 - - [04/Apr/2015:11:06:13 +0000] "GET /shadiCo/item/146 HTTP/1.1" 200 33640 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
37.8.80.203 - - [04/Apr/2015:11:06:20 +0000] "POST /method/pusher HTTP/1.1" 200 96 "http://localhost/shadiCo/item/146" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
37.8.80.203 - - [04/Apr/2015:11:06:20 +0000] "POST /method/pusher HTTP/1.1" 200 96 "http://localhost/shadiCo/item/146" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
```

Edited after use @elcodedocle Code : 
The problem was not ajax or mysql problem , its get_headers() function problem which slow down the request which i use for check if image exists or not, by using this function :

```
public function url_exists($url) {
    if(!empty($url) && $this->is_url($url) && extension_loaded('openssl'))
    {              
            $file_headers = get_headers($url);
            if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found')
            {
              return false;
            }else{

                    $allowed = array('Content-Type: image/jpeg','Content-Type: image/pjpeg','Content-Type: image/png','Content-Type: image/gif');

                     if(!in_array($file_headers[1], $allowed))
                     {
                                    return false;
                     }else{
                                    return true;
                     }                     
             }  
   }else{
        return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: try to use GET instead of POST

Comment: Can u send your log from apache? I mean - are u sure, that it is ajax slow?

Comment: It's probably server misconfiguration (hosts file, DNS conf, routing table, apache virtualhost... something like that). Need the server log for action.php POST ajax request, otherwise it's just blind guessing.

Comment: Also, what's your `action.php` doing exactly? That is the code that really matters. Don't want to be rude, but what you posted is the equivalent of giving us a fish and ask us if we can guess the results of the battle by opening it up and reading its insides.

Comment: @elcodedocle , its just get data ( image, description, comments , etc ... ) about item that user click on it from mysql database, any way see my edited ..

Comment: @elcodedocle thank you for your solution to detect where is the problem, i found it , it's not ajax or mysql problem , its get_headers() problem which slow down the request which i use for check if image exists or not ,, by using this function ,, so is there any idea to speed it up or replace this function , which i put in my question ?!

Comment: Alright, I should be requiring you to post a different question because those are the rules over here, so remember that next time an answer to a question "how do I find what's going on" brings another question "how do I solve this problem", ok? Anyway, I have extender my answer to provide a solution to your problem.

Comment: @elcodedocle thank you for your perfect answers , i appreciate that, and i'll be aware of my questions next time, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to have a problem with client latency, neither building and sending the request nor processing the result.

You should start looking at what's happening on the server.

- Does your server-side script start executing right away? Check there is no significant delay between the moment the request is sent by the browser and the moment the script execution begins. Web server routing or some other kind of server misconfiguration might be delaying the script execution start.
- Which part of your script is slowing it down? you must determine where is the delay by either using breakpoints ([Xdebug](https://xdebug.org) will help you with that), which is the pro way to do it, or by logging the server's timestamp at different points (which in my opinion is more amateurish, but an easier one time solution), for example using [microtime](http://php.net/manual/es/function.microtime.php) and [error_log](http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-log.php):

.

```
<?php

// Execution starts (compare this timestamp with the browser's request timestamp to check for delays on execution start)

ob_start();

$opNames = array();
$opDelays = array();
$start = microtime(true);
error_log("Start time: {$start}");
$time = $start;

// Initialization, read and process input ops, etc ...

// YOUR CODE HERE

$prevtime = $time;
$time = microtime(true);
$delay = $time - $prevtime;
$opNames[] = "Input processing";
$opDelays[] = $delay;
error_log("Input processed at {$time}. Processing time: {$delay}");

// Database access

// YOUR CODE HERE

$prevtime = $time;
$time = microtime(true);
$delay = $time - $prevtime;
$opNames[] = "Database access";
$opDelays[] = $delay;
error_log("Database response received at {$time}. Operation duration: {$delay}");

// Results processing, output formatting...

// YOUR CODE HERE

$prevtime = $time;
$time = microtime(true);
$delay = $time - $prevtime;
$opNames[] = "Results processing";
$opDelays[] = $delay;
error_log("Results processed at {$time}. Processing time: {$delay}");

// Output flushing and end of execution

ob_end_flush();

$time = microtime(true);
$delay = $time - $start;
$maxDelayIndexes = array_keys($opDelays, max($opDelays));
error_log("End of script execution at {$time}. Total processing time: {$delay}. Most expensive operation: ".$opNames[$maxDelayIndexes[0]]);
```

- How can you fix the problem? Ask again when you know what the problem is.

**[EDIT]**

So you've analyzed your script and discovered `get_headers($url)` is what's slowing down the execution.

You want to check if a particular public resource, an image, exists on `$url`

Is this really a remote resource or is it hosted on the same server your application is running? Because if it's a local one maybe a simple `file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT ROOT']."path/to/my/image.jpg")` will do, and that's several orders of magnitude faster than the full HTTP request `get_headers($url)` performs.

If it is a remote resource located on a different server you can still speed up very much the process by using the [PHP curl extension](http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php), which allows to "ping" the resource to get the response code without waiting until the reception is complete (which on a heavy image it can be even more than the 4 seconds you are having problems with). This is how it's done:

```
public function url_exists($url){
  if(empty($url) || !$this->is_url($url)){
    return false;
  }
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // get result as a string, do not output
      CURLOPT_URL => $url, // url to connect to
      CURLOPT_NOBODY => true, // only the header
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, // we don't really care about cert validation for this, do we?
      CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 2 // return error if can't connect in 2 seconds or less
    ) 
  );
  curl_exec( $curl );
  $response_code = curl_getinfo( $curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
  curl_close( $curl );
  if ($response_code === 200){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

On a sidenote, if you still have performance issues on this, you might be interested in exploring [other cURL options](http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php) such as DNS cache expire time in order to speed up DNS resolution, which is usually the slow part of the check when the server IP is not cached.